# Cache busting of JSON files in webpack

Tags: angular, caching, webpack

I have the following code (written in typescript, but could be any JS variant):

```
this.http.get('configs/config.json').subscribe(...);
```

Basically, I'm loading a configuration from a local json file. I would like to have cache busting implemented on the file.
Although I can set up my webpack to modify json files by adding a hash suffix, I would also need to modify all the source files which have references to those files. `string-replace-loader` might do the job, but doing this feels bit odd.

Additionally, in some cases I don't have access to the code lines that make the http call to resource (third-party plugin for e.g. translation that load something like `i18n/[lang].json` so I can't directly modify code and/or name (and thus content hash) is only known in the run-time.

Is there something like URL rewrite for webpack that could solve this?

Comment: What if you injected a hash so that you get `configs/config.json?<hash goes here>`? If the hash changes, then it would invalidate the query. You could inject that easily with `DefinePlugin` etc.

Comment: Where would I inject this hash to? The ts file that loads it (problem here in described in the third paragraph) or do it by renaming file in webpack (windows server doesn't allow this naming)?

Comment: `DefinePlugin` could do it if you have something like `hash = HASH;` and replaced `HASH`.. Then you can do `'configs/config.json' + hash` as usual.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I just need to find a way to make this HASH depending on the actual file content.

Comment: That's a harder problem. If it's just a single file, then you can calculate md5 over the file content with Node.js and inject that. Dealing multiple would be trickier. I don't have enough info to give an exact solution.

Comment: This was helpful enough. I can use something like CopyWebpackPlugin to load files based on pattern, sum their content and extract hash. Only issue is that it would be pretty much duplication of what I'm doing with CopyWebpackPlugin already.
I'll give it more thinking... Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to perform a `transform` pass at `CopyWebpackPlugin`. I don't remember if it allows it already, but I imagine it wouldn't be hard to add. It's possible the calculation would be too late there, though, so another plugin might be the key.

Comment: Yes, problem would be in potential race condition - the hash needs to be generated in CopyWebpackPlugin in transform function but DefinePlugin might already be triggered by that time.

Comment: I just realized something. Since you have the files in the file system, you could set up a `require.context` against them. That would push the problem to webpack and avoid a lot of work (no need for those plugins at all). I have covered the basic idea [here](http://survivejs.com/webpack/advanced-techniques/understanding-chunks/#dynamic-loading-with-require-context-) if you aren't familiar with it already.

Comment: But if that's not possible, I guess it would have to become a pre-process executed before any of the webpack bits to avoid the race condition. You would have to consume the hashes from there.

Comment: If this is solved why not answer yourself and accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use query-params in the URL to avoid caching.
No need to change the filename.

```
this.http.get(`configs/config.json?t=${new Date().getTime()}`).subscribe(...);
```

`new Date().getTime()` will create a unique number for every millisecond.

In case of ngx-translate, you can define your httpLoader factory as

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, '/assets/i18n/',`.json?v=${new Date().getTime()}`);
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This works as cache busting but it will prevent caching completely for this file (each requets will get a file from the server). With hash possibly injected by the Webpack you get both cache busting when file changes and caching when file is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

In webpack we usually rely on the compiler to build the modules and maintain the hashes so chunks are invalidated accordingly when modules and their dependencies change.

If you use `file-loader` for the JSON files and add the [`[hash]`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#hash) option to add an identifier based on their contents, you could change to something like the following and webpack will handle the rest during builds:

```
const configFileUrl = require('configs/config.json')
this.http.get(configFileUrl).subscribe(...)
```

Using loaders is usually the best way to opt in, because this adds modules, enables plugin access and maintains dependencies.